# Permission to open external browser in Android 11 with <queries> in manifest

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-11

Starting from Android 11 `(API 30)`, `packageManager` will throw **NameNotFoundException** even if the app you are querying is installed on the device.

But in my app with `targetSdkVersion 30`, we need to direct the customer to external link to complete survey stuffs. I have heard and tried `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />` but it is high risk permission and might cause app rejection so I'm not using it.

So, I used another method to achieve it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

My question is whether using `<queries/>` might result in possible app rejection by Google? Because I don't wanna risk delaying the release date for client.

Comment: For opening an external browser you use ACTION_VIEW. I dont understand your scenario.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't even bother query for that. The odds that no app exists that can handle ACTION_VIEW is extremely low, maybe even impossible. In any case, I don't think your app would get rejected for that, although that is just my instinct and not based on anything.

Comment: "we need to direct the customer to external link to complete survey stuffs" -- why are you using `PackageManager` for that? Call `startActivity()` with your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. Wrap the `startActivity()` call in `try`/`catch`, and gracefully degrade in the `catch`. This also covers cases that querying `PackageManager` would not. "My question is whether using <queries/> might result in possible app rejection by Google? " -- we have no way of answering policy questions. However, Google specifically recommends using `<queries>` and not using `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`.

Comment: This is because my current project is Flutter app. My team is using a third party lib which uses `packageManager.resolveActivity` manually to check whether user has browser installed before proceeding to redirect them to browser. It started throwing exception after we have upgraded to minSdkVersion 30 few days ago. It was fixed with `<queries>` but I'm concerned whether it would be ground for app rejection. But looks like it's not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify apps(with package name) you interact with Android 11 & above.

Use the below code,

```
<queries>
...
<package android:name = "com.android.chrome" />
<package android:name = "com.chrome.beta" />
<package android:name = "com.chrome.dev" />
<package android:name = "com.google.android.apps.chrome" />
...
</queries>
```

Comment: What if the user does not have chrome installed? And by using your method, we have to list out all possible browsers in the market.

Comment: That is very unusual scenario. But for that case you need to handle exception (using try...catch)

Answer (score 1):

Just Paste this code in your AndroidManifest.xml file. It checks if a browser is available or not. If there is a default browser it directly opens in that.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#check-browser-available